# How do I get a function to be in effect every time something is typed in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, frontend

I am trying to compare the values of two input boxes, then change the border of the boxes when the value of the two boxes are not equal. The problem I am having is in the if statement where I compare the two values of the input boxes, it will never compare equal, except at the beginning where they are both blank, even if they are. I run the function through itself, I run a setTimeout on my function so it checks it every 500 milliseconds. Any help would be appreciated, and I most likely will look at the answers when I wake up in the morn.

```
var passContext = $('#pass').val();
var pass2Context = $('#pass2').val();

      function checkMatch() {
    if (passContext == pass2Context) {
      if($('#passCont').css({borderWidth: 1})) {
        $('#passCont').animate({
        borderWidth: 0
      }, 400)
      }
      //Add button animation
    } else {
      $('#passCont').css({
        border: '0 solid red'
      }).animate({
        borderWidth: 1
      }, 400)
      setTimeout(checkMatch, 2000);
    }
  }

  checkMatch();
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/yz6tgga7/

Comment: But in the fiddle you have provided, you are using `change keyup paste` events.. Your question is misleading and confusing...

Comment: Bind `keypress` on both the `inputs`

Comment: `keyPress` function is not defined anywhere

Comment: Also add `input` event in your attached events...

Comment: I fixed it. I put the two variables passContext and pass2Context in the myCheck function and it works now. Thanks for your guys input.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I had to change. My variables passContext and pass2Context had to be inside my checkMatch function.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you expect. get the logic in my code. see the live demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.stl{
 border:3px solid orange;
}

</style>

<body>
 
Fisrt :<input class="myinput" type="text" name="one" id="myone"> <br>
Second :<input class="myinput" type="text" name="two" id="mytwo">



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myinput").on('change keyup keydown',function(){
   

  var theid = $(this).attr('id');
  

    
    if (theid == "myone") 
    {
     //alert(theid);
     var valone = $("#myone").val();
  var valtwo = $("#mytwo").val();

  if(valone != valtwo)
  {
   $("#mytwo").addClass("stl");
   $("#myone").removeClass("stl");
  }
  else
  {
   $("#myone").removeClass("stl");
   $("#mytwo").removeClass("stl");
  }
    }
    else
    {
     //alert(theid);
     var valone = $("#myone").val();
  var valtwo = $("#mytwo").val();

  if(valtwo != valone)
  {
   //alert("not equal");
   $("#myone").addClass("stl");
   $("#mytwo").removeClass("stl");
  }
  else
  {
   $("#myone").removeClass("stl");
   $("#mytwo").removeClass("stl");
  }

    }

  
  });
 });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the input event or the keyup event

without jquery:

```
var passContext = document.getElementById('pass'),
    pass2Context = document.getElementById('pass2');

function checkMatch() {
  ...  
}

passContext.addEventListener('input', checkMatch, false);
pass2Context.addEventListener('input', checkMatch, false);
passContext.addEventListener('keyup', checkMatch, false);
pass2Context.addEventListener('keyup', checkMatch, false);

// The third param on the addEventListener function is to disable the bubbling
```

With JQuery:

```
function checkMatch() {
  ...
}
$('#pass, #pass2').on('keyup input', checkMatch);
```